# How to make each customLabel on their own line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, listview, uiview, uilabel

I tried to create a custom UIView with 3 labels, name, book and chapter for a bookmark function in my listView. Now i want the labels to be in different lines in the tableView's cell. Which is the best approach or what would you do to make the labels on their own line if you look at my code below? I am new to Objective C and Iphone development.

The outcome should look like this in the list at each cell:

```
--------
name

book

chapter
--------
```

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BookmarkCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
Bookmark *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *chunks = [item.name componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

NSString *name;
NSString *book;
NSString *chapter;

if ([chunks count] > 0)
{
    name = [chunks objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([chunks count] > 1)
    {
        book = [chunks objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([chunks count] > 2)
        {
            chapter = [chunks objectAtIndex:2];
        }
    }
}

UIView * pNewContentView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
CGRect labelFrame= pNewContentView.bounds;
labelFrame.size.width= labelFrame.size.width * 0.25;

UILabel* pLabel1=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel1];

labelFrame.origin.x= labelFrame.size.width;
UILabel* pLabel2=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel2];

labelFrame.origin.x= labelFrame.origin.x + labelFrame.size.width;
UILabel* pLabel3=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
[pNewContentView addSubview:pLabel3];

[cell.contentView addSubview:pNewContentView];

[pLabel1 setText:(name)];    
[pLabel2 setText:(book)];  
[pLabel3 setText:(chapter)];       

//cell.textLabel.text = name;
//cell.detailTextLabel.text = book;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace all `x` with `y` and `width` with `height`. Check the output and adjust the height and width of your labels to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be easier for you to create custom cell in Interface Builder and then just setup your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, there are a lot tutorials with demo on this.

If you want to do that programmatically then it should look something like this:

```
UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,15,300,20)];
name.text = @"some name";
UILabel *book = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,25,300,20)];
book.text = @"some book";
UILabel *chapter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,35,300,20)];
chapter = @"chapter";

[cell.contentView addSubview:name];
[cell.contentView addSubview:book];
[cell.contentView addSubview:chapter];
```